# How to ensure ConcurrentDictionary of collections thread-safety?

Tags: c#, data-structures, concurrency

So here I am implementing some caching layer. Particurally I am stuck with

```
ConcurrentDictionary<SomeKey,HashSet<SomeKey2>>
```

I need to ensure that operations on HashSet are threadsafe too (ergo Update is threadsafe). Is it possible in any simple way or do I have to synchronize in the UpdateFactory delegate? If the answer is yes (which I presume) did any one of You encountered this problem before and solved it?

I want to avoid ConcurrentDictionary of ConcurrentDictionaries because they allocate a lot of synchronization objects and I potentially have around a million entries in this thing, so I want to have less pressure in on the GC.
HashSet was chosen because it guarantees amortized constant cost of insertion,deletion and access.

The aforementioned structure will be used as a index on a larger data set with to columns as a key (SomeKey and Somekey2) much like a database index.

Comment: You could subclass `HashSet` to make it synchronized (but that would probably go against your reason to use `ConcurrentDictionary<SomeKey, ConcurrentDictionary<SomeKey2, SomeValue>>`). Alternatively you could enforce the synchronization yourself after getting from the `ConcurrentDictionary`. This would of course be more work. It almost seems like you expect the concurrency to be done for you without having to incur the overhead...

Comment: The simplest solution is to use lock striping to ensure that operations on the Set are threadsafe. If you are using a mutable, non-concurrent Set then locking on reads would be required. Otherwise an immutable/persistent or concurrent Set would be required, which trades off memory / write performance. A more specialized structure might be possible with more details, but this would be the most pragmatic approach until a higher level of concurrency was required.

Comment: @M.Babcock it's not that I dont expect concurrency to have a cost. I just don't want to pay n times the price. ConcurrentDictionary already provides me with atomic reads and writes the problem with that it requires atomic values stored in it (ergo the immutability). And dictionary allocates 4*Enviroment.ProcessorCount objects for synhronization and if You have 1 000 000 keys You add approximately 32 milion objects to Your gen 2  to walk every time a GC lev 2 occurs. And my concurrency level is surely not 32 milion. More like 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally I decided to go with Immutable set and lock striping because it is reasonably simple to implement and understand. If I will need more performance on the writes (no copying the whole hash set on insert) I will implement reader/writer locks with striping - which should be fine anyway.
Thanks for suggestions.